What Numpy version should I use now/ Is there a way to revert back last pip install (ctrl z for pip install)?
I tried to install tensorflow-hub but this installation changed the Numpy version from  numpy 1.25.2 to NumPy 2.0.2, now Shell can't run programs with this installation (other modules are not compatible now).
What Numpy version should I use now?
This question is more about finding a suitable version of Numpy which will be convenient with the modules required,
In cmd, pip install tensorflow-hub
...
...
Collecting mdurl~=0.1
  Downloading mdurl-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (10.0 kB)

Installing collected packages: namex, libclang, flatbuffers, wheel, termcolor, tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem, tensorboard-data-server, protobuf, optree, opt-einsum, numpy, mdurl, markdown, grpcio, google-pasta, gast, absl-py, tensorboard, ml-dtypes, markdown-it-py, h5py, astunparse, rich, keras, tensorflow-intel, tensorflow, tf-keras, tensorflow-hub
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.25.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.25.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.25.2

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
matplotlib 3.8.3 requires numpy<2,>=1.21, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
gensim 4.3.3 requires numpy<2.0,>=1.18.5, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.
scipy 1.11.1 requires numpy<1.28.0,>=1.21.6, but you have numpy 2.0.2 which is incompatible.

Successfully installed absl-py-2.1.0 astunparse-1.6.3 flatbuffers-24.3.25 gast-0.6.0 google-pasta-0.2.0 grpcio-1.67.1 h5py-3.12.1 keras-3.6.0 libclang-18.1.1 markdown-3.7 markdown-it-py-3.0.0 mdurl-0.1.2 ml-dtypes-0.4.1 namex-0.0.8 numpy-2.0.2 opt-einsum-3.4.0 optree-0.13.0 protobuf-5.28.3 rich-13.9.3 tensorboard-2.18.0 tensorboard-data-server-0.7.2 tensorflow-2.18.0 tensorflow-hub-0.16.1 tensorflow-intel-2.18.0 tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem-0.31.0 termcolor-2.5.0 tf-keras-2.18.0 wheel-0.44.0
...
...

Now when I run a program, the message in Shell
...
...
AttributeError: _ARRAY_API not found

A module that was compiled using NumPy 1.x cannot be run in
NumPy 2.0.2 as it may crash. To support both 1.x and 2.x
versions of NumPy, modules must be compiled with NumPy 2.0.
Some module may need to rebuild instead e.g. with 'pybind11>=2.12'.

If you are a user of the module, the easiest solution will be to
downgrade to 'numpy<2' or try to upgrade the affected module.
We expect that some modules will need time to support NumPy 2.
...
...
ValueError: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96 from C header, got 88 from PyObject



try to do pip install numpy=1.27.0. You cannot revert a pip install action, because pip does not keep records like that

pip install numpy==1.10 (The version you want)

This should restore the package to the new specified version.
Alternatively, you can also try
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall numpy==1.10.5

or uninstall current version with
pip uninstall numpy

and install it again with
pip install numpy==1.10 (The version you want)

